# Simplify nested exponentials and logs with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

How can I get sympy to simplify an expression like `log(exp(exp(x)))` to `exp(x)`? It seems to work on simpler expressions like `exp(log(x))` => `x`. This is a minimal example showing what I've tried so far:

```
import sympy
from sympy import exp, log

x = sympy.symbols('x')

a = exp(log(x))
print a

# Gives `x` automatically, no call to simplify needed

b = log(exp(exp(x)))
print sympy.simplify(b), sympy.powsimp(b,deep=True)

# Gives `log(exp(exp(x)))` back, expected `exp(x)`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of lack of information. I think you want to do this:

```
In [7]: x = Symbol('x', real=True)

In [8]: (log(exp(exp(x)))).simplify()
Out[8]: exp(x)
```